# Fliping An Array of Ones and Zeroes

Tags: algorithm, stack

I am Having a array `A` consists a Array `ones` and `zeroes`. In one operation i can choose a `Range 1 to i` `1<=i<=N` and `flip` the array and `invert` it.
 I had to find the minimum operation needed for this.
For Ex:

```
A = 0010
```

In first operation in range 1 to 4 first we flip the array and invert it

```
A = 1011
```

In second operation in range 1 to 1 first we flip the array and invert it

```
 A = 0011
```

In thrid operation in range 1 to 2 first we flip the array and invert it

```
 A = 1111
```

So three operations are required. 
How I can find the Minumum number of operation

```
My Approach:
```

Make Last Element as one and proceed

```
while(end>=0){

    if(A[end]==1){ end--;continue;}

    int i=0;

    if(A[0]==1) {
     ans++;
     A[0]=0;
     }
    i = 0;
    int j = end;

    while(j>=i){
        // Flip the Array and inverted it.
    }
    ans++;
    end--;

}
```

This is greedy approach and i think it will not work.

Comment: You can save an operation by traversing the array in reverse and appending to a new array.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto would you explain with some example

Comment: @Spektre would you give me link or explain with example

Comment: @Sunny sorry I just spotted you are mirroring the bits not xor-ing neighbors so it is a different problem then I taught. Do you need the solution or just the number of steps?

Comment: also what are the limits of range must it always start from 1? otherwise your example could be done in 2 steps

Comment: Is the goal to always end with all 1's?

Comment: You don't actually say what you're trying to achieve.  We can only guess by looking at your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if this is optimal solution (although it looks like it) I would do this like this (**C++**):

```cpp
int puzzle_flip_invert(int *a,int n)
    {
    int i1,m,N=n,i,j; char b;
    // here print the input a[N]

    // solve the puzzle
    for (m=0;;m++)
        {
        // starting ones -> zeros
        if (a[0]==1)
            {
            for (i1=0;(i1<n-1)&&(a[i1+1]==1);i1++);
            if (i1==n-1) break; // solution found
            }
        // cut ending ones and then ending zeros -> ones
        else for (i1=n-1;(i1>=0)&&(a[i1]==1);i1--,n--);
        // flip and invert a[i] i=<0,i1>
        for (i=0,j=i1;i<=j;i++,j--)
            {
            b=1-a[i]; a[i]=1-a[j]; a[j]=b;
            }
        // here print partial solution a[N] and used range <1,i1+1>
        }
    // here print the result m
    return m;
    }
```

usage:

```cpp
int a[4]={0,0,1,0};
puzzle_flip_invert(a,4);
```

output (sorry did not include the print code as it is platform dependent):

```
0010
1011 range: <1,4>
0011 range: <1,1>
1111 range: <1,2>
--------------
Needed: 3 steps.
--------------

[   0.013 ms]
```

The main idea (partially based on Paul Hankin's suggestion) is to:

1. **if array starts with ones**

   then check how many of them are there together. If the whole string stop you found solution if not flip them and invert so the string starts with zeros. This is important so we can get rid of the ending zeros later.
2. **if array starts with zeros**

   then check how many ones are at the end and cut the array size `n` by them as this part of array is already done. then flip and invert the rest. This will convert as much of last zeros from the cuted part as it can.
3. **goto #1**

**[Notes]**

As I mentioned I do not know if this approach is optimal solution. For that you would need to do a some kind of proof which is not my cup of tea so I would not even try it. Anyway I think this is a good start point ...

Beware the `array` indexing in **C++** is from `0` not from `1` !!! The prints are incremented so the ranges matches your output.

Few more examples:

```
010
101 range: <1,3>
001 range: <1,1>
111 range: <1,2>
--------------
Needed: 3 steps.
--------------

00001111001101110
10001001100001111 range: <1,17>
00001001100001111 range: <1,1>
11110011011111111 range: <1,13>
00000011011111111 range: <1,4>
10011111111111111 range: <1,9>
00011111111111111 range: <1,1>
11111111111111111 range: <1,3>
--------------
Needed: 7 steps.
--------------
```